# Need right word; don't think "sardonic" is it

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for the word(s) that describes a situation where, physically, you'd see someone smiling but shaking their heads, as in "Oh, no, my dear friend has (comically) screwed up again!"  For this situation, I currently use my own emoticon:  : )  : (   : )
I see that some writers use the word "sardonic" to describe the situation above, but dictionaries often attach some cruel connotation to the word.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Bemused, perhaps. See the third definition: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bemused

Answer (score 3):

**wry**

He gave a wry smile. / She smiled wrily.

Answer (score 0):

derisory, mocking, ironic, caustic, jeering, scoffing ?

Comment: Thanks; however, for me it's key that humor is dominant....

Answer (score 0):

The smile makes it sound like **[schadenfreude](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/schadenfreude)** to me

> delight in another's misfortune

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is *rueful*, meaning  “expressing sorrow or regret, esp. when in a slightly humorous way”  ([1](https://www.google.com/#q=rueful)).

Note that like *[wry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wry#Adjective)* or *[wrily](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrily)*,  *[rueful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rueful#Adjective)* or *[ruefully](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ruefully)* are more often attached to the sufferer than to the sympathizer.   On the other hand, *[commiserating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commiserating#English)* or *[commiseratingly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commiseratingly)* ordinarily attach to [empathetic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empathetic) or [sympathetic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sympathetic) onlookers.